# Add a transient property to PFObject subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

How do I add a transient property (not an actual Parse Class column) to a PFObject subclass?

I've tried the following to add a transient property "location":

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "Location.h"

@interface Club : PFObject<PFSubclassing>

+ (NSString *)parseClassName;
@property (retain) NSString *name;
@property (retain) NSString *legalName;
@property (retain) NSString *address;
@property (retain) NSString *address2;
@property (retain) NSString *city;
@property (retain) NSString *state;
@property (retain) NSString *zip;
@property (retain) PFGeoPoint *geoLocation;
@property (retain) NSString *website;
@property (retain) NSNumber *timeOffset;
@property (retain) NSNumber *rating;
@property (retain) NSNumber *serviceRate;
@property (retain) NSNumber *taxRate;
@property (retain) NSNumber *organizationId;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Location *location;

@end


#import "Club.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation Club

@dynamic name;
@dynamic legalName;
@dynamic address;
@dynamic address2;
@dynamic city;
@dynamic state;
@dynamic zip;
@dynamic geoLocation;
@dynamic website;
@dynamic timeOffset;
@dynamic rating;
@dynamic serviceRate;
@dynamic taxRate;
@dynamic organizationId;
@synthesize location = _location;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Club";
}
-(void)setLocation:(Location *)location
{
    _location = location;
}

-(Location *)location
{
    return _location;
}

@end
```

When I add this I get the error "Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type whenever I import Club.h

Comment: The code looks ok to me. What is the type of Location?

Comment: Try adding `@class Location;` before your @interface in the .h file

Comment: Location is an MKMapItem Subclass

Comment: adding @class Location; doesnt do anything, "Location.h" is already imported in the header.